# how to print python list in html table horizontally (django)

Tags: python, html, django

I have a list `l` and want to want to display in html table horizontally. I am new in html and django.

```
l=[10,40,50]
```

I did the fowllowing but it displays vertically

```
          <table>
              <tr><th>grades</th></tr>
              {% for items in l %}
              <tr><td>{{ items }}</td></tr>
              {% endfor %}
          </table>
```

this is what i want to achieve where i can alsp display years:

```
        2019   2018    2017
grades   10     40      50
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not end the `<tr>`, which is the *row*, only the `<td>`:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>grades</th>
    {% for items in l %}
        <td>{{ items }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you pass the years as well, you can typeset these as well, so if the years look for example like:

```
years = range(2019, 2016, -1)
```

We can render a table like:

```
<table>
    <tr><th></th>
    {% for year in years %}
        <th>{{ year }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    <tr><th>grades</th>
    {% for items in l %}
        <td>{{ items }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
</table>
```